# What's this salad of gray lumps in white dressing?

Tags: salad

I can identify the green lettuce at the bottom, but not the physical matter under the red maraschino cherry. I happened upon this on [Open Rice](https://www.openrice.com/en/hongkong/p-cafe-landmark-p2264762) for a popular Western cuisine restaurant in Central, Hong Kong.

1. What are the gray lumps?
2. What white dressing is this?

[image]

Comment: The American food that looks most like that is either macaroni salad or potato salad. And the thing on top could be a cherry tomato rather than a cherry. But if you want to know what's actually shown in the photo, you'd have to visit the restaurant or find a detailed menu online.

Comment: Clicking through to the restaurant's menu, and assuming this is the "deluxe club sandwich", apparently that is what they call french fries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is potato salad, cubes of cooked (boiled) potato in a dressing of mayonnaise. If you are looking to replicate this, the typical [cha chaan teng (茶餐廳)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cha_chaan_teng) style potato salad might have some sweetened condensed milk, something like a 4:1 ratio of mayonnaise to condensed milk. Also, the garnish appears to be half of a cherry tomato, rather than a maraschino cherry.

Comment: The shape of the lumps is quite unlike a regular potato salad - the pieces are strangely curved.

Comment: @Stephie potatoes are round, so the curved pieces are from the side of the potatoes.

Comment: @Max of course, but some (multiple) pieces seem to be curved twice - like a fat ‘C’ or celery stalks. (But without the ridges.)

Comment: @Stephie Possibly pear or apple (coated in mayonnaise)?

Comment: @DebbieM. I never knew you can put mayonnaise or dressing on fruits???

Comment: @Vast In the US at least, there are many fruit salads that use mayonnaise, sour cream or the like. Waldorf salad is one of the more famous ones.